# Twitter search returns no statuses - even in their API tool

Tags: twitter

We have noticed that a simple scheduled pull of latest statuses from a particular account has stopped working and on inspection, it appears that no statuses are returned. The query are using is literally just a from search:

```
from:Mgmt_Futures
```

Or in full form:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3AMgmt_Futures
```

The account settings all look OK and the application authenticates just fine. When using Twitter's Apigee console we see no results.

When creating a widget in the account, there are no tweets displayed unless you select the option to 'Only show top tweets'.

So I'm not sure why nothing is being returned here.

Comment: have you authorized?

Comment: @Chamilyan in Security and Privacy on the account, all tweets are protected, so they should appear in a search. The app we have is set up with OAUTH correctly. However even before we look at the app, I would expect a search on that timeline to work via their own API (Apigee) tool: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3AMgmt_Futures

Comment: if the tweets are protected (locked,private) they won't appear in search

Comment: Sorry @Chamilyan I meant to say tweets are NOT protteced.

Comment: When I tried to login with oAuth using the APIgee console, I get results with this request https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3AMgmt_Futures it doesn't show the actual statuses with details but pointers instead.

Comment: @Chamilyan yes exactly. There are recent tweets so I would expect them to be in the status array, I don't understand why that's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) is *not* a comprehensive list of all Tweets.

It is currently returning your most recent tweet (6th October) - but the previous tweets are from over a month ago (8th September).  The Search API doesn't archive every tweet and will often only return ones from the last month or so.

Your only option, if you want **all** the Tweets from a particular use is to use the `GET statuses/user_timeline` method https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline